# How to POST data to child iframe from parent window in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, post, iframe

How we can post some data to an iframe in AngularJS application, using window object? I know how to do it in JavaScript. But I need to do it in Angular way.

I tried

```
$window.postMessage("message","*");
```

and

```
$window.parent.postMessage("message","*");
```

But these methods doesn't works! I can transfer data from my iframe to angular app using second method. But for some reason, both methods doesn't work in parent-child (app to iframe) communication.

Anyone knows why? Anyone knows how to implement this (in Angular way)?